# CLOSED Append a word onto word list

Tags: java, arrays, append, cpu-word

i'm having a bit of trouble trying to append a word back into the word list.

The program counts how long a words length is, then stores it so the output shows something like:

Words of Length 7 56

I've got it so it's counting the number of words correctly, but the output is not putting the correct word count with the right word length.

So it should be
Words of Length 1 0

but mine shows
Words of Length 1 97

(which is the correct count for words of length 2).

I'm not sure how to fix this.

I feel it should be something like this:

```
wordList[wordCount-1] = word;
```

(The -1 is so I don't get an Array out of bounds error).

```
  import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project2
{
    static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // ALWAYS TEST FIRST TO VERIFY USER PUT REQUIRED INPUT FILE NAME ON THE COMMAND LINE
        if (args.length < 1 )
        {
            System.out.println("\nusage: C:\\> java Project2 <input filename>\n\n"); // i.e. C:\> java Project2 dictionary.txt
            System.exit(0);
        }
        int[] histogram = new int[0]; // histogram[i] == # of words of length n

        /* array of String to store the words from the dictionary. 
            We use BufferedReader (not Scanner). With each word read in, examine it's length and update word length frequency histogram accordingly.
        */

        String[] wordList = new String[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        int wordCount = 0;
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(args[0]) );
        while ( infile.ready() )
        {
            String word = infile.readLine();
            // # # # # # DO NOT WRITE/MODIFY ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE # # # # #
            if (wordCount == wordList.length)
                wordList = upSizeArr(wordList);
            // test to see if list is full. If needed do an up size (just like Lab#3)

            wordList[wordCount++] = word;

            // now you may safely append word onto list and incr count
                int wordLength = word.length();
                if (word.length () > histogram.length)
                    histogram = upSizeHisto(histogram, wordLength);
            // look at the word length and see if the histogram length is AT LEAST
            // word length + 1. If not, you must upsize histogram to be EXACTLY word length + 1
            histogram[word.length()-1]++;

            // now you can increment the counter in the histogram for this word's length

            //  # # # # # DO NOT WRITE/MODIFY ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE  # # # # #
        } //END WHILE INFILE READY
        infile.close();

        wordList = trimArr( wordList, wordCount );
        System.out.println( "After final trim: wordList length: " + wordList.length + " wordCount: " + wordCount );

        // PRINT WORD LENGTH FREQ HISTOGRAM
        for ( int i = 0; i < histogram.length ; i++ )
            System.out.format("words of length %2d  %d\n", i,histogram[i] );

    } // END main

    // YOU MUST CORRECTLY COPY THE STRING REFS FROM THE OLD ARR TO THE NEW ARR
    static String[] upSizeArr( String[] fullArr )
    {   
        String [] newArr = new String [fullArr.length*2];
        for (int count = 0; count < fullArr.length ; count++)
        {
            newArr[count] = fullArr[count];

        }


        return newArr; // just to make it complie you change as needed
    }
    static String[] trimArr( String[] oldArr, int count )
    {
        String[] newArr = new String[count];


        for ( count = 0; count < newArr.length ; count++)
        {
            newArr[count] = oldArr[count];

        }


        return newArr;  //return null; // just to make it complie you change as needed
    }

    // YOU MUST CORRECTLY COPY THE COUNTS FROM OLD HISTO TO NEW HISTO
    static int[] upSizeHisto( int[] oldArr, int newLength )
    {
        int [] newHisto= new int[newLength];


        if (oldArr.length > 1)
        {
        for (int count = 0; count < oldArr.length  ; count++)
        {
            newHisto[count] = oldArr[count];

        }
        }

        return newHisto; // just to make it complie you change as needed
    }
} // END CLASS PROJECT#2
```

Question: how do append a word back into the word list array (word list is from a text file). Without using Arrays or hashes.

Comment: please show more of your code.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Updated. Please, the full code runs fine. It's just that very small part that I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

So you're initial check is correct. Check to make sure the index in wordList is valid when inserting a new word. Then modify wordList by doubling its capacity. Where you go wrong is when you subtract 1 from the wordCount. This will fail first time because wordCount is 0, 0 - 1 = -1 and that's an invalid index. Simply use the wordCount as is and increment. You can even use the post increment when adding the word.

```
if (wordCount >= wordList.length)
    wordList = upSizeArr(wordList);
    // test to see if list is full. If needed do an up size (just like Lab#3)

wordList[wordCount++] = word;
```

Comment: That still doesn't fix it. It still reads Words of Length 1 96. Which is supposed to be for words of length 2. If I remove the -1 from the histogram incriment, it throws a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Comment: @LadyRen if you do System.out.println(word); what gets printed? or show an example of the file you are using and put it in the question

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, you print the array index as the word length, but the index is *one less than* the word length (remember `histogram[word.length()-1]++`?);

```
// PRINT WORD LENGTH FREQ HISTOGRAM
    for ( int i = 0; i < histogram.length ; i++ )
        System.out.format("words of length %2d  %d\n", i,histogram[i] );
```

The line should end`, i+1, histogram[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (word.length() > histogram.length)
  histogram = upSizeHisto(histogram, wordLength);
```

to

```
if (word.length() >= histogram.length)
  histogram = upSizeHisto(histogram, wordLength+1);
```

And

```
histogram[word.length() - 1]++;
```

to

```
histogram[word.length()]++;
```